# PHP Hello Analytics Reporting API V4 with OAuth 2.0

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to access the Google Analytics API for web applications using PHP, like described in this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-php

I have followed all the steps precisely, however was not been able to make it running. I have managed to debug so far that I found out about where the problem is.

[image]

When OAuth consent screen pops up and I click Allow, application does not get authorized. I just keep seeing the same popup. Also, if I check authorized apps in my google account, it is not listed there.

Another interesting fact is that Hello Analytics Reporting API V4 using JavaScript is working just fine.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js

Does anybody have a clue about what could be wrong with my app authorization?

OK, now I have additionally discovered it has something to do with localhost. Once I have uploaded the same code to live server, it is working just fine. But I cannot get it working on locahost. Does anybody have an idea how to setup Credentials or whatever to make it working in development environment (localhost)?

Comment: It sounds like the session isn't getting set.  Can you post your code the tutorial code looks right to me but I don't have the power to test php from here.

Comment: I have added the code, however, it is the same like in tutorial. I think the problem is related to application.

Answer (score 1):

Check your browser extensions (i.e. Disconnect)  may be blocking the auth token.

Comment: Can you expand?  How would an extension block the token?  Any specific extensions that are know to do this? (Disconnect(?))  ...And good answer, btw :)

Comment: @cullub - I had the same issue. HelloAnalytics is a  javascript implementation thus runs client-side.  White-listing in Disconnect, disabling Disconnect in incognito and Firefox with no tracking/ad blocking  worked.  

From the docs: " Google returns the access token on the fragment of the response, and client side script extracts the access token from the response.  Since a fragment is not returned to the server, client-side script must parse the fragment and extract the value of the access_token parameter." [link]https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do I need to do in my Firefox browser?

Comment: Try restarting in safe mode:  Under the `Help` menu, click `Restart with Add-ons Disabled`.  If this fixes your problem, then the problem has to do with an add on that you have installed.